# SyntaxError in Python IDLE 2.7 but not in PythonTutor

Tags: python, syntax

I'm getting a SyntaxError: invalid syntax in response to the following code when I run in it IDLE, but not in PythonTutor.  Can anyone help with why?

```
def apples(x, y):
    try:
        result = x/y
    except ZeroDivisionError, e:
        print "division by zero!" + str(e)
    else:
        print "result is", result
    finally:
        print "executing finally clause"

apples(3, 4)
```

The SyntaxError is associated with the 'apples' in apples(3,4)

Comment: Fix your indention. It's hard to tell what the problem is here.

Comment: What exact error do you get?

Comment: Just did that - I'm new to Stack Overflow's formatting.

Comment: The exact error is: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: funny, it is happening for me too, are you pasting the code in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could replicate you error was pasting the code into `idle` including `apples(3, 4)`.

If I pasted the `function` first then ran the function with `apples(3, 4)`, it works fine.

```
>>> def apples(x, y):
        try:
            result = x/y
        except ZeroDivisionError, e:
            print "division by zero!" + str(e)
        else:
            print "result is", result
        finally:
            print "executing finally clause"
apples(1,3)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 

>>> def apples(x, y):
        try:
            result = x/y
        except ZeroDivisionError, e:
            print "division by zero!" + str(e)
        else:
            print "result is", result
        finally:
            print "executing finally clause"


>>> apples(2,3)
result is 0
executing finally clause
```

Comment: Ahhhhh Thanks so much!  This totally worked.  I will remember not to paste into the shell both the code and the inputs at the same time.

Comment: No worries, you're welcome. I would highly recommend using Ipython, there are numerous features that make working with python even more fun. You can just copy code and type `paste` in the shell and it will run you code, that is just one of many cool features.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you are showing should run correctly in Python 2, but will fail in Python 3 due to the `print` statements.

Here is how you might make it work in Python 3, assuming that is your problem.

```
def apples(x, y):
    try:
        result = x/y
    except ZeroDivisionError, e:
        print("division by zero!" + str(e))
    else:
        print("result is", result)
    finally:
        print("executing finally clause")

apples(3, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input - I see the difference between the two.  However, I'm in Python 2.7.8; is your correction still applicable?

Comment: @user3882253, Are you absolutely sure that that is the version your `IDLE` is running?

Comment: Absolutely: Python 2.7.8, IDLE 2.7.8, & Tk 8.5.15.  I'm on a MacBook Pro w/ 10.9.4

Comment: Does my answer fix the issue?